# React Native java files deleted

Tags: javascript, android, react-native

I used react-native-rename to change my app name, but after that MainActivity.java and MainApplication.java have been deleted. Is there a way to retrieve or rebuild them?

Answer (score 0):

It’s solved by using
react-native upgrade —legacy true